# Given an integer x^3 ≡ n (mod p), can we find x?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cubic-reciprocity

Okay, I have this for a class homework question. If we are given n and p, I know a few things:

- If p≡1 (mod 3), then we can use the theorem of cubic reciprocity to determine whether there exists an integer x such that it falls into n's congruence class.
- If p≡2 (mod 3), we can say that there definitely is an integer x such that it falls into n's congruence class.
- If p≡0 (mod 3), I don't know.

The issue is that when using this theorem the best we can do is say that there exists an x, not identify the original x. The question asks whether we can ever know what x originally was, given its remainder mod p.

I don't know if this is more properly under CS stackexchange, but this felt much more mathematical in nature.

Comment: The third case is simply $p=3$.

Comment: @lhf: I was going to ask if $p$ had to be prime, but I suppose it makes sense to assume that it must be...

Comment: In fact the homework problem uses the student's ID in a formula. It isn't necessarily prime.

Comment: For composite $p$ (shudder!) it is a long story.  For $p$ prime of the form $3k+2$, there is an explicit formula for the cube root of $n$ modulo $p$.  But I don't know whether that is the question.

Comment: My intuition tells me that because the cardinality of each of a modulus's congruence classes is infinity, the best you could do given which congruence class an unknown number falls into is say whether or not it could be a perfect cube, not whether it is or not.